# How can I do git checkout on a repository with submodules?

Tags: git, branch, git-submodules

Suppose I have a repository `X` with a sub module `A`.  Now suppose I want `X` to have two branches:  master and development.  I want master to have a different revision of `A` than development does.  How can I switch back and forth between these branches?

I've got a repository set up that does this (but using real names instead of fake ones!).  The problem is that whenever I do `git checkout master` from development, I get the following:

```
$ git co master
M       A
Switched to branch 'master'
```

It looks like it's not putting `A` back to the commit that master references.  Is there any way around this?  Both `git submodule sync` and `git submodule update` don't seem to change anything.

Answer (score 0):

You need made a git checkout before